# Is there a place I can look to see how much rep I earned one day excluding the ones from accepts?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I can manually check how many of my answers were accepted, multiply that by 15, and subtract that from the total rep gained that day to see how much more I'll be able to gain from votes.

But is there a place I can look to see how much rep I earned one day excluding the ones from accepts?

Comment: You can parse the contents of your reputation log at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation - which is live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1243909) that does that.

It queries all your posts and links them to the votes those posts got. In the votes table upvotes and down votes are recorded as a row with votetypeid = 2 for an upvote and votetypeid = 3 for a downvote. By grouping on the creationdate of the votes and summing the number of rows of each votetypeid we can calculate how many up and down votes you received on that single day. Doing the multiplication of upvotes * 10 and subtracting downvotes * 2 will give the estimate of the reputation gained / lost on that day.

This query doesn't take reputation limit or bounties into acount.

```sql
select v.creationdate
     , sum(case when votetypeid =2 then 1 else 0 end) upvotes
     , sum(case when votetypeid =3 then 1 else 0 end) downvotes
     , sum(case when votetypeid =2 then 1 else 0 end) * 10 - 
       sum(case when votetypeid =3 then 1 else 0 end) * 2 [reputation]
from posts p
inner join votes v on v.postid = p.id
where p.owneruserid = 13552470
and v.votetypeid in (2,3)
group by v.creationdate
order by v.creationdate desc
```

When run today this is the result:

[image]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.

If you want live data you might want to script something for this Stack API call

[reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/13552470/reputation?site=stackoverflow)

that is documented here: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#ids=13552470&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true

Comment: I don't understand this very well. Besides, I was wondering if there's simple place to check how much rep i earned excluding rep from accepts daily, like the trophy icon.

Comment: @AnnZen that is what the table above shows.

Comment: @Ann Stack Exchange Data Explorer is *the* tool for checking things like this. You can check out its ["help"](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about it. Rene composed a quick query that gives you the amount of reputation you earned in a single day.

Comment: @rene But I meant the current day, so we will be aware that our rep is soon reaching the limit. In the case I'm acknowledging here, how much we earn in the past days don't matter anymore.

Comment: @AnnZen I've added a link to the API. I can't further test that as I'm IP banned at the moment due to a throttle violation caused by my testing.

Comment: I've closed this as a dupe of the FAQ on auditing rep gain/loss. If you want to add some discussion of SEDE queries related to rep into that Q&A, I'd have no problem with that. Others might find it more useful than the text-only /reputation endpoint.